# How can we install gke on bare metal to use Anthos services

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-anthos

I'm planning to deploy a system running K8s on Centos and setup 2 VMs on GCP with GKE to centralize the cluster management of both GCP and bare metal for backup and workload sharing (20% on GCP and 80% on bare metal) according the documents on GCP, the GKE and Anthos services are just supporting the VM with vSphere only, so my question is that deployment model will be possible and how can we do that?

Comment: As you mentioned, Anthos supports vSphere, not bare metal. You will need to use vSphere for this to work

Comment: so there is no way to extend the usage of existing k8s bare metal servers for workload sharing with anthos services ?

Comment: not yet, vSphere is a requirement for now. Whether this is a technical limitation or just not in scope yet is not clear. I recommend opening a feature request with Google through their issue tracker